# shortcut for below regular expression matching even index between 4 to 16

Tags: c#, regex, regex-group

Regex.IsMatch(Source, @"^[0-9a-fA-F]{4}$") || Regex.IsMatch(Source, @"^[0-9a-fA-F]{6}$")||
Regex.IsMatch(Source, @"^[0-9a-fA-F]{8}$") || Regex.IsMatch(Source, @"^[0-9a-fA-F]{10}$") ||
Regex.IsMatch(Source, @"^[0-9a-fA-F]{12}$") || Regex.IsMatch(Source, @"^[0-9a-fA-F]{14}$") ||
Regex.IsMatch(Source, @"^[0-9a-fA-F]{16}$"

can anyone suggest shorcut for the above regex expression matching even index between 4 to 16

Comment: Try `Regex.IsMatch(Source, @"^([0-9a-fA-F]{2}){2,8}$")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want two to eight pairs of hex digits.

```
^(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{2}){2,8}$
```